# How do create ODBC data source by using oracle instant client?

Tags: database, oracle, odbc, datasource, instantclient

As I knew, Oracle Instant Client is free from OTN for anyone to use in a development or production environment. But in order to create a ODBC data source on windows, i need a **tns service name**?  How can I create odbc data source on windows os by using oracle instant client?

Answer (score 0):

Check the ODBC installation instructions http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/oci/odbc-ic-releasenotes-094306.html :

On Windows

1. Install the Instant Client Basic or Basic Light package.
2. Download the Instant Client ODBC package. Unzip it
   in the same directory as your Basic or Basic Light package.
3. Execute
   odbc_install.exe from the Instant Client directory. If Instant
   Client is 11g or lower, start the command prompt with the
   Administrator privilege.

On Linux I sometimes hand edit my .odbc.ini file to change the TNS connect string in the `ServerName` field, for example to set it with the 'Easy Connect' TNS syntax:

```
ServerName = localhost/orclpdb
```